# PHP HTML echo variable with <span style> and <div class>

Tags: php, html

```
$color="#FF0000";
$text = "Text";
```

I have this code but it has a syntax error.

```
echo '<div class="text"><span style=\color": $color\">$text</span",'</div>';
```

Whats wrong? I would like to echo the $text with $color color with "text" div class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '<div class="text"><span style="color:', $color, '">',$text,'</span></div>';
```